# Reverse Saturation Current of BJT

Tags: bjt

This may be a weird question but for a BJT, we have

[image]

\$I_S\$ is the reverse saturation current and \$I_C\$ is the collector current which flows through all three parts of the BJT.

Now my question is, \$I_S\$ should also flow through all three parts of the BJT, so can't we just add/subtract \$I_S\$ from \$I_C\$ via KCL? Is that where the -1 comes from?.

Comment: -1 is there to make the Ic zero when Vbe is zero.

Comment: \$I_S\$ is a *property* of the transistor, not a physical current that actually flows through it.  The \$I_S\$ in that equation is close to the reverse saturation current of the base-emitter junction, but the equation is off by a factor of \$\beta\$.

Comment: I discuss it [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/330612/38098) and [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/287455/38098).