# Thermal voltage of a BJT vs. diode voltage drop

Tags: bjt

I'm learning about the hydrid-pi model of the BJT transistor:

[image]

In this model, the base and the emitter have a resistance \$r_{\pi}\$ in between. The voltage between the base and the emitter is apparently called "thermal voltage" and at room temperature it is approximately \$26mV\$. This voltage divided by the bias current gives the resistance \$r_{\pi}\$.

But normally in circuit analysis it is assumed that a transistors base-emitter junction has the voltage of a diode, approximately \$0.7V\$ across it. **Isn't there a contradiction?**

Answer (score 1):

There's no contradiction if you're using the model for what's it's intended for.

The hybrid pi model is *only* useful for the dynamic gain of the transistor (and then at only one specific emitter current), not about the static biassing.

If you want a model for the static biassing, then a more useful one is to replace the input resistor with a diode, and the \$g_m V_{be}\$ current source with \$\beta I_b\$

Answer (score 0):

The thermal voltage of a BJT, \$V_\mathrm{t}\$, is not the default voltage across a junction. It originates from the Shockley diode model from which large signal BJT models are formed:

$$
I = I_\mathrm{s} \left(\mathrm{e}^\frac{V}{N V_\mathrm{t}} - 1 \right)
$$
where Is is the saturation current, Vt the thermal voltage, and N the forward emissivity coefficient or ideality factor.

The 0.7 V you mention also can be derived from this model, which is referred to as the forward voltage, when using parameters suitable for a silicon diode (other semiconductors have different forward voltages). Typically a forward current is assumed, lets say 1 mA, which when solving the above equation for V, produces a voltage of around 0.7 V. This voltage is similar for a range of currents due to the exponential nature of the equation, which is why it is commonly stated. To try this out the parameters for a silicon pn junction are around \$ I_\mathrm{s} = 10^{-14}\ \mathrm{A}\$, \$ N = 1\$, and \$ V_\mathrm{t} = 25\ \mathrm{mV} \$.

The thermal voltage actually arises from the junction temperature, given by 
$$
V_\mathrm{t} = \frac{kT}{q}
$$
where q is the charge on an electron, k is Boltzmann's constant, and T the temperature in Kelvin. For room temperature this comes out around 25 mV (depending on how hot you like your room :) ).

A BJT features two pn junctions that are typically modelled using the Shockley model, plus a bit extra. I recommend reading up on the Ebers-Moll model. The Hybrid Pi model is derived from large signal models like the Ebers-Moll model by finding the DC operating point, and from this finding the derivatives of currents with respect to voltages. The derivative of a nonlinear impedance linearises the model around a point, giving transconductances and resistances depending on which derivative is used.

Comment: Just so things are clear to anyone reading (I'm not assuming anything about you), the hybrid-\$\pi\$ model is one of ***three*** non-linear models for the BJT -- which are entirely equivalent to each other. I've written about the topic [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/252199/38098). What's important to remember is common usage of "hyprid-\$\pi\$" is really the "small-signal linearized version" of the full non-linear hybrid-\$\pi\$. The original published papers make these distinctions. So, there are ***three*** equivalent Ebers-Moll level 1 models. Not only one of them.