# Is this hybrid pi model of a BJT unileteral or bileteral?

Tags: bjt, model

In introductory texts, the BJT is said to be a unilateral device. I think it means that the base current is only a function of Vbe; and Vbe is not function of Vce and Ic(?)
Is the following BJT model unileteral or bileteral?

[image]

In other words, according to the above model, is the base current or Vbe function of any output parameters like Vce or Ic?

Comment: That's a small-signal version (using derivatives) and is useless for large-scale results. The large-scale models (lacking Early Effect \$r_o\$, though) are [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/252199/38098). If you focus on active mode and take the deriviative, you'll get the linearized hybrid-\$\pi\$. But it's only valid close-by around a specific operating point.

Comment: I see but Im asking only about the approximate model in the question. Is that model unileteral?

Comment: Well, if I felt I understood the exact question I might try and offer a suggestion. But I don't feel as though I do. So I'm not sure which direction to head. That said, do you understand how a current mirror works?