# Do Ebers-Moll model cover all working modes of BJTs?

Tags: bjt, ebers-moll

I mean the normal working modes (cutoff, forward/reverse active, saturation).

Or an other form of the question: Do Ebers-Moll cover the whole working domain of BJT (in potential and current values)?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: The model does not take into account the inner capacities, high frequency effects, heat dependency. Besides these covers all modes?

Comment: Remember this: "All models are **wrong**, some models are **useful**". It depends on what mode the transistor is in and how you want to use it if a model will give a result that can be relied upon. Also: if some model covers "everything", then why do other models exist?

Comment: I would not say "wrong" - models are models, which means: The are accurate enough for representing the most important and most relevant transistor properties. In this context, remember: Even no equations are 100% correct in electronics. We always have to face neglections (of 2nd order effects) and simplifications..

Comment: Yes it does cover the four working areas you mention in DC quasi-static operations. The alphas (forward and reverse) and the saturation currents dependencies are somehow hidden, you should have a function of Ic,Vcb,temp etc. describing them.

Comment: The Ebers-Moll "model" comes in three flavors (prior to Gummel-Poon arriving.) I discuss the level-1 model [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/252199/38098). This does NOT include bulk resistance, charge storage (which are in the level 2 model), or bandwidth modulation (which appears in the level 3 model.) Gummel-Poon takes a more physically-aligned approach for bandwidth modulation and includes the so-called Late Effect, when it does so. All of these models work in all quadrants. (These are the full non-linear models and are not some simplified, "linearized" small-signal model.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments and some research:
Ebers-Moll is quite accurate approximation of a BJT's low frequency processes.
It does not deal with delay effects coming from inner capacities.
But for a low freq textbook circuit describes well the four states mentioned above.